# Investigate sum using Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

My problem is defined as follows, use the Cauchy criterion to investigate convergence of the following series: 
$$S(n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)}{n}$$

How do I start? My inuition is that the sum diverges, since $cosx$ is bounded and we have the harmonic series in the expression. My idea is to prove that $$S(n) \geq K\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ and then use the Cauchy criterion on the harmonic series to show that it diverges and therefore S(n) also must converge. Or is this just a way to avoid the original problem?

Comment: Are you speaking about $S(x)$ or $S(n)$ ?

Comment: I think that using $2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) x\right)$ in place of the numerator could help.

Comment: Claude: $S(x)$, sorry. And yes, I used that expression my self, but I don't know if the general approach really solves the problem that my teacher asks.

Answer (score 1):

The problemn is easily solved using Dirichlet's criterion. Let $a_n(x)=\cos(n\,x)-\cos((n+1)\,x)$ and $b_n(x)=1/n$. Then
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^na_k(x)\Bigr|=|\cos x-\cos((n+1)\,x)|\le2.
$$
We have:

1. The partial sums of $a_n(x)$ are uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}$
2. $b_n(x)$ is decrasing for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
3. $b_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

By Dirichlet's uniform criterion the series converges uniformly on on $\mathbb{R}$.